# Batch file : doubles quote inside double quotes

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file excuting a command excuting a command :

```
forfiles /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c ffmpeg -i C:\dummy.mkv -i @relpath -vcodec copy -acodec copy @relpath.mkv"
```

If the `@relpath` parameters as space, I get the error:

> No such file or directory

I've been searching like one hour in the internet, I found no solution.

I tried `\"@relpath\"`, `^"@relpath^"`, `""@relpath""`... nothing worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, since it took me about 4 minutes to find the correct way to convert all my files recursively, and the rest of the hour no to find a solution to such a simple problem as "my file path contains spaces"...

---

**[Edit /]** - *from comments, (converted from image and into English).*

Please watch here, the excecution of `FORFILES /S /P . /C "cmd /c echo @RELPATH && dir @RELPATH"`, you can see at the end, while executing the `dir` command, the `The system cannot find the file specified.`. If you manually type `dir` with the name of the file, it works fine. That's my problem; precisely.

```
C:\dum my>FORFILES /S /P . /C "cmd /c echo @RELPATH && dir @RELPATH"

".\dir 2"
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 0CC7-3CE2

 Directory of C:\Dum my\dir 2

23/12/2018  20:38    <DIR>          .
23/12/2018  20:38    <DIR>          ..
23/12/2018  20:38               438 te st.file
               1 File(s)            438 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  30,868,815,872 bytes free
".\dir1"
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 0CC7-3CE2

 Directory of C:\Dum my\dir1

23/12/2018  20:38    <DIR>          .
23/12/2018  20:38    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  30,868,815,872 bytes free
".\my file"
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 0CC7-3CE2

 Directory of C:\Dum my

23/12/2018  20:22               352 my file
               1 File(s)            352 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  30,868,815,872 bytes free
".\dir 2\te st.file"
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Dum my>
```

Comment: It is my experience that `@FILE`, `@FNAME`,`@EXT`, `@PATH`, `@RELPATH` etc. were already doublequoted! Are you sure that `@RelPath` is what you need?

Comment: @Compo : sorry, I don't get your point. The command, as I posted it, had no double quotes at first. And it doesn't work when files have spaces in their names. I tried with files without space successfully.

Comment: If you try : forfiles /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c echo ^"@relpath^"", it gives you correct names.
If you try forfiles /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c dir ^"@relpath^"" you get many "file not found"

Comment: @Compo said that the value of variable `@RELPATH` is already double-quoted. Try `FORFILES /P %userprofile% /M NTUSER.DAT /C "cmd /c echo @file @fname @RELPATH"` as an example.

Comment: @double-beep : yes ok. Exécuting FORFILES /S /P . /C "cmd /c echo @RELPATH" works fine. But exécuting FORFILES /S /P . /C "cmd /c dir @RELPATH" drives to "file not found" when I got spaces in filenames. Please give it a try too.

Comment: Please watch here, I took a screen shot of the excecution of
FORFILES /S /P . /C "cmd /c echo @RELPATH && dir @RELPATH"
-> https://imgur.com/a/cxAUGrE
Sorry, it's in french. You can see at the end, while executing the dir command, the "Le fichier spécifié est introuvable." erros occurs, meaning "file not found". If you manually type dir with the name of the file, it works fine.
That's my problem; precisely.

Comment: The "dum my" folder contains 2 folders "dir 2" and "dir1", and a file "my file". "dir 2" folder contains just one file named "te st.file"

Comment: Why do you use __FORFILES__ at all? Why not using `for /R %%I in (*) do ffmpeg.exe -i C:\dummy.mkv -i "%%I" -vcodec copy -acodec copy "%%~dpnI.mkv"` or even better `for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /A-D-H /B /S 2^>nul') do echo ffmpeg.exe -i C:\dummy.mkv -i "%%I" -vcodec copy -acodec copy "%%~dpnI.mkv"` which avoids processing the `*.mkv` files already created on FAT32 and ExFAT drives. For help on command __FOR__ run in a command prompt window `for /?` and `dir /?` for help on command __DIR__.

Comment: And even on __FORFILES__ must be used instead of __FOR__ for some unknown reason, why running `cmd` with option `/C` and a command line to execute by `cmd.exe` instead of directly running `ffmpeg.exe` with the parameters by `forfiles`? This does not make sense to me for the posted command line in your batch file. BTW: Help on command __FORFILES__ can be read on running `forfiles /?` in a command prompt window. __FORFILES__ instead of __FOR__ makes only sense on using option `/D` of __FORFILES__ in my point of view. In all other cases __FOR__ is the better choice for doing something in a loop.

Comment: @Encore, I have edited your question to include the output from your image, you may now delete that comment and the one below it, as they're no longer required. Now, what happens if you use the same command, but exclude directories and as I implied before, change `@RelPath` to `@Path`? i.e. `ForFiles /S /C "Cmd /C If @IsDir==FALSE Echo @Path && Dir @Path"`, _(note: I removed the unnecessary `/P .`)._

Comment: If you use your `ffmpeg` command within the test directory in your image, you will clearly see that it is executing four lines; `ffmpeg -i C:\dummy.mkv -i ".\dir 2" -vcodec copy -acodec copy ".\dir 2".mkv`, `ffmpeg -i C:\dummy.mkv -i ".\dir1" -vcodec copy -acodec copy ".\dir1".mkv`, `ffmpeg -i C:\dummy.mkv -i ".\my file.txt" -vcodec copy -acodec copy ".\my file".mkv` and `ffmpeg -i C:\dummy.mkv -i ".\dir 2\te st.file" -vcodec copy -acodec copy ".\dir 2\te st.file".mkv`.. I'm fairly sure that this isn't what you wanted to do. You may prefer to use  the `@IsDir` option, used in my comment above.

Comment: @Mofi, I use FORFILES cause I found I wanted to execute a command recursively and the first example I found was this one. Why would I use FOR /R better than FORFILES ? I don't have the "already created" situation you talk about. I talked about a precise problem. Using cmd /c is, as your told useless. I was like this when I copied/pasted it from Internet. It doesn't do any harm, so why talking about what's useless when we want to know what is harmfull ? You can correct my english mistakes ass well if you like.

Comment: @Compo : using Path instead of Relpath made the trick, **thank you very much :)**
The working command I use is this one : `forfiles /s /m *.* /c "ffmpeg -i B:\home\FLAC\gervais.mkv -i @path -vcodec copy -acodec copy @path.mkv"`
**Thank you all for your precious help !**

Answer (score 1):

While OP has solved the problem with the use of `@PATH` instead of `@RELPATH`, why `@RELPATH` fails?

As stated by Compo and seen in the command output, quotes are not the problem.

The reason for the problem is what the current active directory is. Let's made a little change in the command

```
forfiles /S /P . /C "cmd /v /c echo @RELPATH & echo !cd! & dir @RELPATH"
```

to get this output (sorry, spanish windows version)

```
W:\dum my>tree /f
Listado de rutas de carpetas para el volumen Nuevo vol
El número de serie del volumen es 0000-0000
W:.
├───dir 1
└───dir 2
        te st.file


W:\dum my>forfiles /S /P . /C "cmd /v /c echo @RELPATH & echo !cd! & dir @RELPATH"

".\dir 1"
W:\dum my
 El volumen de la unidad W es Nuevo vol
 El número de serie del volumen es: 0000-0000

 Directorio de W:\dum my\dir 1

24/12/2018  11:00    <DIR>          .
24/12/2018  11:00    <DIR>          ..
               0 archivos              0 bytes
               2 dirs  47.507.652.608 bytes libres
".\dir 2"
W:\dum my
 El volumen de la unidad W es Nuevo vol
 El número de serie del volumen es: 0000-0000

 Directorio de W:\dum my\dir 2

24/12/2018  11:00    <DIR>          .
24/12/2018  11:00    <DIR>          ..
24/12/2018  11:00                 0 te st.file
               1 archivos              0 bytes
               2 dirs  47.507.652.608 bytes libres
".\dir 2\te st.file"
W:\dum my\dir 2
El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.

W:\dum my>
```

When `forfiles` reaches `te st.file`, the current active directory has changed from `W:\dum my` to `W:\dum my\dir 2`.

That means that while the output of the `@RELPATH` is correct from the `forfiles` point of view, we have a wrong path for the `dir` command that is executed from a different directory.

As `@PATH` returns an absolute path, the elements being processed can be reached independently of current active directory change.

Comment: I was going to explain that too in my answer, but since the `Dir` command was only an example, _not relevant to the actual task_, I decided not to.

Comment: @Compo, `dir` or another command, the directory change is the cause of the failure in this case and could be in any other case using `@RELPATH`. I saw the problem was solved but as I think the cause is relevant I have added the answer for futher reference. If you prefer to include it in your answer, I have no problem in deleting mine.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my initial comment, *and information in subsequent comments*, I would suggest replacing `@RelPath` with `@Path`

```bat
ForFiles /S /M *.* /C "ffmpeg -i C:\dummy.mkv -i @Path -vcodec copy -acodec copy @Path.mkv"
```